# Is there $f:S^1 \rightarrow S^1$ such that $f \circ R_\alpha = R_{-\alpha} \circ f$?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

As the title displays, I am to determine wether there exists a homeomorphism $f$ of the circle such that $f \circ R_\alpha = R_{-\alpha} \circ f$, with $R_\alpha$ being the standard rotation with $\alpha \in R$

I tried two somewhat different approaches, but not very fruitfully:

Consider the functional equation given by the relation above, we then have

$f(x + \alpha) = f(x) - \alpha$

Which has one solution given by $f(x) = 1-x  $, a homeomorphism of $[0,1]$as seen with:

$f(x+\alpha) =1 -x -\alpha = f(x) - \alpha$

In this case, I have found a homeomorphism of the circle that satisfies the above relation. (although I am not convinced)

I tried another approach, demanding(unjustified) that we can use fourier series:

Suppose we can expand the relation in fourier series, then by equating coefficients we find that:

$c_ne^{2\pi i n(x+\alpha)} = c_ne^{2\pi i n(x-\alpha)}$

Hence we find that $1 = e^{4\pi i \alpha}$ and the only conclusion we can make is that $\alpha = \frac{k}{2}$ for $k \in Z$. I am not sure how to tie these analyses together such that to come to a sufficiently satisfactory conclusion, does such a homeomorphism exist?

Comment: A certain reflection works for all $\alpha$.

Comment: I have given it some thought, and I am not sure if the first psrt of my analysis above constitute such a reflection, if not, do you have Another hint?

Comment: It's a tad unclear because you flip between maps $f \colon S^1 \to S^1$ and $f \colon [0,1] \to [0,1]$. But if I parse everything right, your map corresponds to the complex conjugation $z \mapsto \overline{z}$. And we clearly have $\overline{e^{i\alpha} z} = \overline{e^{i\alpha}}\overline{z} = e^{-i\alpha}\overline{z}$. Well, there's more to be had from there, for every $\beta$ the map $f_\beta \colon z \mapsto e^{i\beta} \overline{z}$ has the desired property.